# Gerar um relatório utilizando pdf(Jasper), utilizando PHPJasper de uma lista de dados um JSON

Tags: php, java, json, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

estou tentando gerar um relatorio no jasper utilizando a classe PHPJasper, consumindo de um arquivo .json os dados de uma lista conteudo do json:

```
{"listaProdutos": [
  { "mac": "123", "quantidade": 10 },   
  { "mac": "233", "quantidade": 1 },    
  { "mac": "6565", "quantidade": 5 },   
  { "mac": "123", "quantidade": 10 },   
  { "mac": "233", "quantidade": 1 },    
  { "mac": "6565", "quantidade": 5 }]}
```

mas quando eu tento rodar da esse aviso/erro de java:

```
Error filling reportUnable to get value for JSON field "mac" of class java.util.List.
```

como posso converter esta no json ou tenho que fazer algo no arquivo .jrxml porque estou utilizando o php ?

segue o arquivo jmxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.5.final using JasperReports Library version 6.20.5-3efcf2e67f959db3888d79f73dde2dbd7acb4f8e  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="teste2_A4_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="48b36d2d-a294-42f2-94fa-07cd52e28f1b">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="mac" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="quantidade" class="java.util.List"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="da4ffefe-90f5-45ef-97c9-9c0d2d232a72"/>
                <text><![CDATA[mac]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="170" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="24a187e5-515c-409d-bdaf-5e01cf130309"/>
                <text><![CDATA[quantidade]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="49" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="50" y="5" width="100" height="30" uuid="5af40782-09ef-4e08-bd9e-97613a5cb24f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mac}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="170" y="5" width="100" height="30" uuid="72269469-f9b5-4322-8b9b-bff69ad4d86e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantidade}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

utilizei jaspersoft-sdtudio para modelar o .jrxml